# python build from source: cannot build optional module sqlite3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I am building python (version 3.5) from source in order to get the latest version. I can `make` python and install it, but several "optional" modules including _sqlite3 are not installing:

```
$>./configure --prefix=/my/prefix && make
```

Yields the following:

> ...
>
> Python build finished successfully!
>
> The necessary bits to build these optional modules were not found:
>
> _bz2                  _lzma                 _sqlite3
>
> _ssl                  _tkinter              readline
>
> To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.

I (frustratedly) installed sqlite3 from source also to ensure sqlite3 development files exist somewhere, and I believe I have set the necessary `lib` and `include` paths as per the related [lzma module install tutorial](http://www.devsumo.com/technotes/2013/04/building-python-3-3-with-lzma-on-linux-and-os-x/):

```
$> find / -name libsqlite3.so
/home/username/myproject/lib/libsqlite3.so

$> find / -name sqlite3.h
/home/username/myproject/include/sqlite3.h

$> echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/home/username/myproject/lib

$> echo $LDFLAGS
-L/home/username/myproject/lib

$> echo $CFLAGS
-I/home/username/myproject/include
```

And yet, when I run `./configure --prefix=/my/prefix --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions && make`, I am given the above error that `_sqlite3` (amongst others) was not installed because the necessary bits were not found.

Based on [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12023773/python-3-3-source-code-setup-modules-were-not-found-lzma-sqlite3-tkinter), it seems I may need to change `setup.py`? Is that correct?

Is there really no better way than hacking up the python `setup.py` script?

By the way, I realize that installing `sqlite-dev` with `yum` may fix this issue and put the relevant `sqlite3` files somewhere obvious to the python installation, but I am not positive that I will be able to do that due that due to limited repository access.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `setup.py` script does not check any environment variables for the location of the `sqlite3.h` file or any other related files, and therefore changing environment variables is insufficient to allow python to find the files, unless `sqlite3-dev` packages are installed into the "standard" directories.

The following snippet of possible `include` directories for sqlite3 is taken from `setup.py` (for Python-3.5.0):

```
sqlite_inc_paths = ['/usr/include',
                    '/usr/include/sqlite',
                    '/usr/include/sqlite3',
                    '/usr/local/include',
                    '/usr/local/include/sqlite',
                    '/usr/local/include/sqlite3',
                     ]
```

From that, its clear that if sqlite3 is not installed in a "standard" system location such as /usr or /usr/local, then the header files will not be found.

To fix the issue, add in `/path/to/my/personal/sqlite/include` into the above `sqlite_inc_paths` array:

```
sqlite_inc_paths = ['/path/to/my/personal/sqlite/include',
                   ...]
```

And sqlite module will be found.

**Automated install**. To automate the above change, a  perl one liner can be used to make the above change:

```
$> perl -pi.orig -e "s|(?<=sqlite_inc_paths = )\[|['/path/to/my/personal/sqlite/include',\n|" setup.py
```

`sed` can also be used, but the `-i` in-place flag doesn't work on all systems.

Answer (score 17):

This link provided the solution for me building Python 3.5.  Specifically for Ubuntu but helped figure it out for CentOS6 as well.

[Install missing packages before compiling Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12023773/python-3-3-source-code-setup-modules-were-not-found-lzma-sqlite3-tkinter)

More specifically for Ubuntu server 16.04:

```
for pkg in build-essential zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev liblzma-dev libncurses5-dev libreadline6-dev libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev libgdbm-dev liblzma-dev tk8.5-dev lzma lzma-dev libgdbm-dev
do
    apt-get -y install $pkg
done
```

Comment: I think `tk-dev` should work the same as `tk8.5-dev`, but may apply to a wider range of cases. For instance, on MXLinux 17, the available tk version is 8.6, and installing `tk-dev` seems to have worked for me.

Comment: You don't need a for loop here, you can just do `apt-get -y install build-essentials zlib1g-dev ...` and list all packages.

Comment: Also check https://youtu.be/rpkQ_1pg7Tc?t=336