# Pywikibot: _lzma module missing

Tags: python-3.x, wikipedia, lzma, pywikibot

I've developped a Python script which use Pywikibot.
The scripts works fine on Windows 11 but i need to run it on Linux Server with CentOS 7.

But, there was an issue involving a missing module named _lzma.

```
File "/opt/scripts/10_-_One_Shot_Scripts/dlweb_wikipedia_extract_page_list.py", line 21, in <module>
    import pywikibot
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pywikibot/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pywikibot import config as _config
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pywikibot/config.py", line 68, in <module>
    from pywikibot.logging import error, output, warning
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pywikibot/logging.py", line 36, in <module>
    from pywikibot.tools import deprecated_args, issue_deprecation_warning
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pywikibot/tools/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    import lzma
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/lzma.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _lzma import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_lzma'
```

I tried to install [Pylzma](https://pypi.org/project/pylzma/) but it didn't fix the issue.
Following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12023773/python-3-3-source-code-setup-modules-were-not-found-lzma-sqlite3-tkinter), i've installed dependencies:

```
yum install yum-utils
sudo yum-builddep python3
```

but it didn't fix the issue either.

I didn't use a virtual env by the way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after lots of searching around and [following this](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/2921#issuecomment-1341904484),it seems that this module should have been installed during Python installation.
So, i've re-installed Python (and upgrade from 3.9.17 to 3.9.19) and everything work fine.